# Why isn't my inline working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Below is a HTML Code but the `display:inline` isn't working. Am not able to understand why. But `display:flex`, `display: -webkit-box;`, `display: -webkit-inline-box;` , `display: inline-flex;` are working fine;

When i use `display:inline` on class position

[image]

When i use `display:flex` or `display: -webkit-box;` or `display: -webkit-inline-box;` or `display: inline-flex;`  on class position

[image]

Below are the HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="padding: initial;">
<label class="control-label col-sm-12">Sample type :
</label>
<br>
<div class="col-sm-12 position">
 <div style="margin-right: 15px;">
 <label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" id="tee" name="qpd_type" value="5" checked >Type 1 
</label><br/>
</div>
<div>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" id="cia" name="qpd_type" value="2" >Type 2
</label>    
       </div>
   </div>


</div>
```

Can somebody help me figure out why i cant use `display:inline`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get the bullets inline or the whole group?

Comment: i just want to bring type1 and type 2 on the same line. so i tried every possible ways using `display: inline` to bring it inline using chrome developer mode. i want it working using `display: inline`

Comment: Remove <br/> between your <label class="radio-inline">, bootstrap class do the magic tricks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Remove the `<br />` tag from your code.

```css
.radio-style {
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="padding: initial;">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-12">Sample type :
  </label>
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-12  position">
    <div class="radio-style">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="tee" name="qpd_type" value="5" checked>Type 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-style">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="cia" name="qpd_type" value="2">Type 2
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, Simply you can place the two radios into the same div. You don't need any extra css. :)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="padding: initial;">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-12">Sample type :
  </label>
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-12  position">
    <div>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="tee" name="qpd_type" value="5" checked>Type 1
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="cia" name="qpd_type" value="2">Type 2
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="padding: initial;">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-12">Sample type :
  </label>
<br>
<div class="col-sm-12 position">
 <div style="margin-right: 15px;">
 <label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" id="tee" name="qpd_type" value="5" checked >Type 1 
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" id="cia" name="qpd_type" value="2" >Type 2
</label>    
       </div>
   </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.radio-inline{
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
```